# Prepend a div to a div hiding last child

Tags: html, loops, prepend

I am planning to prepend two divs at certain interval of time to a main div which holds 5 divs. When i prepend a new div it should hide the last div in the list.

Here i have made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vivekdx/53aht/

Html

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="child">1</div>   
 <div class="child">2</div> 
 <div class="child">3</div> 
 <div class="child">4</div> 
 <div class="child">5</div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{ width:300px; height:300px; background:#eee;}
.child{ width:280px; margin:10px; height:40px; background:#ccc; float:left; text-align:Center; font-size:30px;}
```

Script

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
{       
 setInterval(function () 
  {
$(".container").prepend('<div class="child">6</div>'); 
   }, 1000);
 }
```

But it is not working good.

When i prepend 6th div 5th have to be hided likewise 4th div for 7th div ...

And also i haven't looping it correctly. Guide me here

Comment: setInterval should not be used!!!!.

If the execution of your code is longer then the interval then it will be executed in an unknown time and can result in different order then the one you expect.

for example: iteration #X started but before it finished iteration #X+1 started and finished (since interval fired every X milliseconds) so the results will be the output of #X+1 and only then #X.

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/53aht/11/ on how to convert your code to setTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

So you only want to have the first five elements visible. You can limit the collection to all elements starting with nth using jQuery [slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method.

```
// prepend a <div />, then get all the children, skip the first 5 and hide the rest.
$(".container").prepend('<div class="child">6</div>').children().slice(5).hide();
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/53aht/4/

Comment: Could you clarify? If you want to add only two divs after certain delay, then you should use setTimeout.

Comment: Yeah i tried that it loops infinitely instead of stoping at two divs

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want to do.
    http://jsfiddle.net/53aht/11/

but keep in mind that your DOM is growing every time you are adding new div so consider removing (delete) it form the DOM.

```
var counter = 10;

function addDiv() {
    $(".container").prepend('<div class="child">' + (++counter) + '</div>');
    setTimeout(addDiv, 1000);
} 

addDiv();
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:#eee;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man.. How to stop it after prepending two divs and delay prepending first div

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) 
{
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".container").prepend('<div class="child">6</div>').children().slice(5).hide(); 
    } , i * 1000);
}
```